# multi-selection [combo] boxes

Tags: multi-select, combobox

My selection is still a 'popup' style instead of always being open [a box] with the options vertically aligned to the top ie a combo-selection box.

i am using the following code within a fields for block:

```
 <%= t.select(:teams, thisT,
     {:multiple => true, :size =>5}) %>
```

where thisT = 
[[4, "JudysBiz (4)"], [5, "testJ (4)"]]

produces the following html code:

```
<select id="game_6_teams" name="game[6][teams]">
<option value="4">JudysBiz (4)</option>
<option value="5">testJ (4)</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, the structure in the html code does not show as a multi-select box. 
i tried to set the first param as 'teams[]' instead of :teams but the html code came out as:

```
<select id="game_6_teams[]" name="game[6][teams[]]">
<option value="4">JudysBiz (4)</option>
<option value="5">testJ (4)</option>
</select>
```

and it still does not show up as a combo-select box...
What am I missing?

Comment: update: i tried <pre><%= t.select('', thisT,
          {:multiple => true, :size =>5}) %></PRE> and the code came out as <pre> <select id="game_6_" name="game[6][]"> <option value="4">JudysBiz (4)</option>
<option value="5">testJ (4)</option> </select>
which gave me the [] at the end of the name, but still no multiple tag!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= t.select(:teams, thisT, {}, {:multiple => true, :size => 5}) %>
```

Syntax is as follows:

```
select(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

can be found here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer if it worked for you.